# Powershell populating the value of an array based on a hash table

Tags: arrays, hashtable, powershell-4.0

I have an array($array) and a hash table($hashtable) as shown below.

[image]

I want to set the Price/Kg column in $array from the Value column in $hashtable. This is what I have tried so far.

[image]

I am not getting a way to populate the Price/Kg column based on Item Name. Am I missing a loop? Can somebody please guide me in the right direction?

P.S. Please ignore the Quantity in decimals.

Comment: `foreach ($el in $array) { $el.'Price/kg' = $hashtable[$el.Item] }` BTW the code in the question should be plain text, not a screenshot: paste it, select the code, click the `{}` button or press Ctrl-K to format it as a block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @wOxxOm. And going forward, I will keep your suggestion in mind.